# Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Requires extended permission: read_stream

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Requires extended permission: read_stream thrown in /home/a1607618/public_html/base_facebook.php on line 1033

my app tend to read user wall posts

```
if ($user)
{
    $comments = $facebook->api('/me/home');
    d($comments);
}

function d($d){
    echo '<pre>';
    foreach ($d as $a => $b)
    {
        print "$a: $b\n";
    }
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

i give my app extended permission: read_stream  through Apps_*>connectme*_>Permissions

and here is the line 1033

```
protected function throwAPIException($result) {
    $e = new FacebookApiException($result);
    switch ($e->getType()) {
        // OAuth 2.0 Draft 00 style
        case 'OAuthException':
        // OAuth 2.0 Draft 10 style
        case 'invalid_token':
        $message = $e->getMessage();
        if ((strpos($message, 'Error validating access token') !== false) ||
           (strpos($message, 'Invalid OAuth access token') !== false)) {
            $this->setAccessToken(null);
            $this->user = 0;
            $this->clearAllPersistentData();
        }
    }

    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: Please [debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) your access token to check if the access token has the `read_stream` permission.

Comment: i fixed this the problem is that as u mention the access token hasn't the read premission thanks for notify me